# WebSphere Portal Advanced Url Generation

Tags: websphere-7, websphere-portal

I like to parse a parm to a portlet on a page, but I have many vHost on my WebSphere Portal 7 server.

http://bsp0.servername.dk/myportal/Home/niceuri/!ut/p/...

http://bsp1.servername.dk/myportal/Home/niceuri/!ut/p/...

http://bsp2.servername.dk/myportal/Home/niceuri/!ut/p/...

I can't find my page...

```
final SelectionAccessorFactory selectionAccessorFactory = (SelectionAccessorFactory) portalstateManagerService
                .getAccessorFactory(SelectionAccessorFactory.class);
        SelectionAccessorController selectionAccessorCOntroller = selectionAccessorFactory
                .getSelectionController(url.getState());
        selectionAccessorCOntroller.setSelection(page_uniquename);
        if (selectionAccessorCOntroller != null) {
            selectionAccessorCOntroller.dispose();
        }
```

I get this error:

```
com.ibm.portal.state.accessors.exceptions.UnknownUniqueNameException: EJPEI0158E
```

Have already visited

[Portal 6.1 and 7.0 Advanced URL Generation Helper classes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21461911)

[Creating a link from a servlet to a page in a virtual Portal](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=688&ca=portall2&uid=swg21271209)

[How to create a link to a portlet (Standard API) that passes parameters to that portlet](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=688&ca=portall2&uid=swg21322423)

I found this comment *@param pageName This is the uniquename and one thing to be aware of is that this is scoped to the virtual portal* on

[Portlet URL generation common methods. URL generation services](http://ibmportalsoa.blogspot.dk/2011/06/portlet-url-generation-common-method.html)

How I determine which vHost I should be looking at ?

**Update 21 may 2013**

I tried to use bsp0.servername.dk17525 as URL-Context in my ServerContext Class

This is the hardcoded version

```
public String getHomeProtected() {
    return "/myportal/bsp0.servername.dk17525";
}

public String getHomePublic() {
    return "/myportal/bsp0.servername.dk17525";
}
```

I got bsp0.servername.dk17525 from WebSphere Portal Administation -->> Virtuel Portel ...